# HTML5 Graphics in Subtitles using Webvtt

Tags: html, video, subtitle

I'm trying to achieve having little graphics in the video subtitles (Webvtt format) displayed by the `<track>`-Element in HTML5 (using Chrome).
I tried it with CSS so far using `content:url()` or `background-image:url()` but wasn't successful.
Does somebody have any ideas or tips how I can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1/ you can try to add div over video tag with z-index, and do not use track.
2/ then you write javascript function that update the div with your subtitles
3/ you can 'css' it ;)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that without the use of javascript

Answer (score 0):

use ::cue selector like this:

```
::cue {
  color: #FFF;
  background: transparent;
  text-shadow: black 0 0 0.2em;
  font: 1.2em sans-serif;
}
```